# Remove duplicated Scala Applications in the memorized list in Eclipse

Tags: scala, eclipse-plugin

I'm using Scala plugin 3.0 in Eclipse Juno. When I run a Scala program using "Run As >> Scala Application". Eclipse will launch a new Scala Application and then run it. If this program has  run before, Eclipse still launches a new one instead of using the memorized old one. For example, I ran AggregateActionTest.scala several times, eclipse will generate many applications instead of one. I do not like this style. Is there any way to handle this problem?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid that by hitting the run button in the tool bar or using its key binding instead of selecting *Run As...* > *Scala Application*. I prefer to set Eclipse up to always launch the previously launched application (*Preferences* > *Run/Debug* > *Launching*, at the bottom, *Launch Operation*), and define a custom key binding for that (*Preferences* > *General* > *Keys*, filter for *Run Last Launched*).